# Translate KeyDown keycode to string (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to translate a keypress into the string corresponding to the chracter. Something like this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(event.which));
});
```

except that this code does not take into account capitalization and does not work for special character, e.g. ",". This:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(event.which));
});
```

seems to the trick, but it can not prevent default browser actions (such as go back on backspace) and there seem to be browser compatibly issues.

Is there any better way, that works across browsers and keyboard layouts ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to reliably get the character from the `event.which` property at an event type other than `keypress`.

If you're questioning that statement, use the demo at  [this page](http://asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html). The `event.which` property can only be translated correctly at a `keypress` event.

If you want to ignore capitals, use the `.toLowerCase()` method.

Comment: Downvoted for what reason? The answer is correct: `event.which` holds the same value for `@` and `2` at the `keydown` event, while the `keypress` event returns the correct charCode for `@`.

Comment: Maybe because you did not answer the actual question, which is how to prevent the default browser action. You might be correct, but it still does not answer the question. I suggest you expand it to include a solution for the default action.

Comment: @FelixKling I would disagree that that is the main question.

Comment: @FelixKling But, as I mentioned in my answer, it's not possible to get the character code **and** the browser-event. I have answered the first question, and explained why the second question cannot be answered with satisfication.

Comment: Ha I see... well, that was the message I took out of the question but  reading it a second time... anyways, I did not downvote... just thinking aloud :)

Comment: +1. This is pretty much the same answer I would've given, although actually in general you can suppress default behaviour in `keypress` in all major browsers. However, for backspace navigating to the previous page it seems this doesn't work. In this specific case, just use `keydown`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not surprising that `keydown` event is not giving you upper case characters, since it is controlled by SHIFT key, which may or may not be pressed at the time.

To prevent default browser action simply return false from your handler.

What browser compatibility issues are you having?

Answer (score 0):

You can use same trick to get character code corresponding to key pressed. To prevent default browser actions you can try this-

```
event.preventDefault(); //For all major browsers

event.returnValue = false; //For Internet Explorer
```

Comment: or just `return false` from the handler

Comment: @Maarten - I did read the question and what i figured from that is you have already found a way to get correct key code from event and want a cross browser way to prevent default key actions. Excuse me if my understanding was not correct. The way i suggested, actually prevents default key action across browsers.

Comment: @liho1eye - return false does the trick, but setting returnValue to 'false' has more priority. I have tried this code and it works perfectly in all browsers.